# Is it possible to add a description to the Cloud Endpoint Java fields in the API Explorer?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoint, google-cloud-console

I try to add a description for field on java google endpoint like this :

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/adexchangebuyer/v1.2/adexchangebuyer.accounts.get

On field id there is a description : The account id (integer)

Theres is an annotation like @Named to add description ?

```
 @Named("valueX")  Double valueX,
```

I can't update the .discovery files because it's generated.

Do you have any idea to add description ? Because there is only a value (integer) near the field

It's java api.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're talking about parameter descriptions, not field descriptions. The [new Endpoints framework](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java) supports this by using the `com.google.api.server.spi.config.Description` annotation.